# MonoTouch - Images in interface builder [?] feedback needed

Tags: xcode4, interface-builder, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I know from past experience that when I add an image to interface builder, I will see a [?] during preview, and it will look OK at execution.  Has there been any work around for this, or does anyone know if the new alpha version that uses xCode 4 fixed this?

I need to port a WPF application over that uses tons of images and it will be extremely challenging doing this without images to actually look at.

I appreciate any feedback

Anthony G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoDevelop 2.8 Alpha 1's Xcode 4 support should solve this. Content files from the MonoDevelop project appear as resources in the Xcode project, and therefore can be accessed by Xcode 4's Interface Builder.

Comment: After looking at known issues and the fact that I need this launched in less than 30 days, I decided to just try restructuring my images used and do all the layout before any coding to make sure its perfect with little lag. Also purchased 8 gigs of rar I just received today to keep compiling time fast, but its good to know this is an issue  that was resolved =)